# How to fully mask my computer without using tor?

Tags: proxy, ip

I want to mask myself and therefore I configured a proxy server. I use debian and squid 2.7.

It actually works fine, however, I visited the site whatismyip.com and I can still see that I'm accessing via a proxy. However, I would like to mask myself completely as if the request came from the other machine. I know that I could also use Tor, however, in my case this is not possible.

Any suggestions how I can mask myself such that I cannot be tracked back to my orginal machine?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to browse the Internet safely?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6440/how-to-browse-the-internet-safely)

Answer (score 0):

Tor is probably your best bet, but if that isn't an option consider finding a reputable VPN you think you can trust.

Ultimately it depends who your adversary is. If you're living in a despotic regime with access to the VPN or the ability to strongarm them you're probably not going to do very well.

But if you pay a reputable company outside your country that hopefully wouldn't sell you out then you should be okay.

Tor is better though. You don't have to trust a company to keep you safe(r). There are still problems with Tor too (correlation attacks by people who own entry and exit nodes or monitor large portions of the internet.

There are way to many risks to say you wont get tracked back to your machine, but these methods will make it harder.